# Google analytics, can you get a list of all user with an accompanying unique ID?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm (very) new to Google Analytics and somewhat to API's - so excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to get a list of all users (who visited our site) that have an accompanying unique ID. A unique ID that would allow me, for example, to create a relationship between the user and their location, or the user and their device.

Using the query explorer I cannot see if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, Google analytics does not store user identifiable information in this manner.

If you are storing your internal system user id ad a custom dimension then you could get that back.

You should consult [Best practices to avoid sending Personally Identifiable Information (PII)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

> To protect user privacy, Google policies mandate that no data be passed to Google that Google could use or recognize as personally identifiable information (PII). PII includes, but is not limited to, information such as email addresses, personal mobile numbers, and social security numbers. Because laws across countries and territories vary, and because Google Analytics can be used in many ways, consult an attorney if you are in doubt whether certain information might constitute PII or not.